# Populate a table that should have an X amount of rows with default values with a big insert query? Or can it done somehow by default?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, query, insert

I have a table lets say calendar

```
Table Calendar --> idCal (int) , numberOfFields (int)
```

And each Calendar has asigned a number of fields

```
Table Field --> idField(int), textField(text), idCal (int) *fk
```

Point is right now, each time an user register, he is assigned a calendar, once the numberOfFields is populated, I select that value and generate an insert query similar to:

```
INSERT INTO Field (textField, idCal) Values ("","idOfTheGeneratedCalendar") , ("","idOfTheGeneratedCalendar") ......
```

Until I have a number of rows equivalent to numberOfFields from the table Calendar. Where each idField(int) begins at 0, and its an autoincrement up to whatever the numberOfFields is

I do that for each user. Point is... is there a better way to do this without building huge insert queries with aprox 3000 values each using a for iteration? Should I be concerned?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `generate_series()` for that:

```
insert into field (textfield, idcal)
select '', c.idcal
from calendar c
where idcal = 42
  cross join generate_series(1, c.numberoffields) as g(f)
```