# Trying to understand how to use postgresql generate_series() for this operation

Tags: postgresql, query, insert

First of all, im coming from this question, where I was recommended to use generate_series() , but after some adjustments in my db, I dont really understand how to create such sentence
This is the old question: [Populate a table that should have an X amount of rows with default values with a big insert query? Or can it done somehow by default?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264375/populate-a-table-that-should-have-an-x-amount-of-rows-with-default-values-with-a)

But I will rephrase the question again:

Those are my initial tables

- `Users`: id(int) PK, weeks_to_live(int)
- `Calendar`: id(int) PK, user_id (int) (FK -> Users(id))*
- `CalendarField`: id(int) PK, text(text), rating(int), calendar_id(int) (FK ->Calendar(id))*, week_number(int)

Point is, when I generate my calendar in my app, actually my Users, and Calendar tables get filled properly.
Upon a generation they will end up looking like this

`users`

```
id   weeks_to_live
1    3
2    2
```

`calendar`

```
id   user_id
1    1
2    2
```

That part is fine, but I need my CalendarField table to be autogenerated too, and thats where supposedly generate_series() should come into action, so they will end up looking like this

`CalendarField`

```
id    text     rating    calendar_id   week_number
1     ''       0         1             0
2     ''       0         1             1
3     ''       0         1             2
4     ''       0         2             0
5     ''       0         2             1
```

As you can observe:

- `id`: is autoincremental
- `text`: always defaults to "",
- `rating`: always defaults to 0,
- `calendar_id` (fk) : is the relation with each calendar, who has an amount of calendarFields row equaling to the number up to weeks_to_live in users
- `week_number`: this number, should begin at 0, and keep incrementing while its < than weeks_to_live in the users table

Now my question is, how do I generate that last insert so my CalendarField table ends up filling with that info?. I suppose that with generate series, I wont need to create an enormous insert with == weeks_to_live values in case it gets huge. But I don't understand how to do it.

Or should I do a giant Insert then?

Comment: I highly recommend to use lower case names, e.g. `calendar_field` rather than `"CalendarField"`. That will save you a lot of headaches in the future. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join `users` and `calendar` and then cross join that with a `generate_series()`.

```
insert into calendar_field (text, rating, calendar_id, week_number)
select '', 0, c.id, g.wn
from calendar c
  join users u on u.id = c.user_id
  cross join generate_series(0, u.weeks_to_live) as g(wn);
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3cecf581d932e4a39e3563566af33d7a)

Comment: It works, and thanks for your comment relating to the lowercase stuff since it was failing too because of that. I will change the names